# Java Android Eclipse: R classes disappear on their own

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got a strange problem with R Classes in Java Eclipse (There are two R Classes, one in com.nameProject e one in android.support-v7). Well, when I add an ImageButton to my project, apparently everything is alright, my project doesn't take over any errors. But when I export my project (I create APK), R Classes disappear from my project ON THEIR OWN! So, the exporting fails and my project hasn't got anymore R Classes and it is incorrect.

This is the Manifest of my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.puccio"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegistratiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registrati" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CredenzialiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_credenziali" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FantaFoodActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fanta_food" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: sometimes it happens when you have "hidden" errors in your project that the IDE couldn't see, just when you generate an apk. BTW, it should print the error issues at `Messages` tab. What do you see there?

Comment: thank you, i solve my problem